# Django migrations - default entries (inserting rows in tables as part of migration)

Tags: django, migration

**Background:**

I'm dealing with quite complex django application and I'm looking for a way to make my life a little bit easier.

One of the models (tables) serves as source of "options" for most "select lists" in the system (simple field <-> dictionary construct). It should always be populated with the default values and/or extenden when the there are new entries provided with a new version of the system.

I manage it all now manually so:

1. I run migrations for the main app
2. Unload the dictionary tables from the dev enviroment
3. Insert them manually into the enviroment I'm currently upgrading
4. I migrate the rest of the apps which may contain refferences to the dictionary tables

All of this because of default values provided in ForeignKeys.

**Actual Question:**

Is it possible to add table entries (table content) to the makemigrations process for particular tables??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do anything you like in a migration via the RunPython operation. This is called a data migration and is [fully documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations).

Comment: Thank you! I somehow missed that one! May seem obvious but it wasn't for me. EDIT: I assume I have to write each insert line "by hand" but it's still much cleaner solution than what I do now.